# Python http.server Create Multiple Instances

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, server

How do you create multiple servers with Python's runtime command `python -m http.server`?

The command creates a server based in `C://Python/Python35` with `index.html` as its home base. If you have two folders, how would you create a server for each of the folders.

#### Edit

You can also do that ouside of the `C://Python/Python35` folder if you do `python -m http.server`.
I have figured out how to create multiple servers with @shadow's help, but when I attempt to connect to the server with `192.168.xxx.xxx:8000` it times out, but on my computer, it works. Why can I not connect to the IP?

Comment: What do you mean by 'another time period'?

Comment: @Shadow I'll use the servers at different times.

Comment: If you're using the server at different times - then what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Shadow I have two different folders. How do you create a specific server based on each folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wish to run multiple `http.server` instances in parallel - you will need to define different port numbers for each.

By default, port `8000` is used, but this can be overridden on the command line like so;

```
python -m http.server 8001
```

This server will run on port 8001 instead of the default.

Now all you have to do is run this command from whatever directories you want shared in this manner, with a different port for each one. One way to do this, is to use `cmd.exe` to navigate to the folder you wish to expose, then run the command from there.

If you do not have python in your PATH, then using

```
C:\Python\Python35\python.exe -m http.server 8002
```

for example should do the trick.